# KendoUI Hide a div inside a tool tip if <p> tag is empty

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

Using the KendoUI dataViz library, the tooltips that display within my line charts contain a div with a child p tag. The contents of this p tag are dynamic, when the p tag is empty and when the data point is hovered on I run a function that checks the length of content within the paragraph tag and if it's empty hides the whole containing div.I'm having an issue where the div seems to only hide for a split second and then show it self again while the mouse remains over the data point. [Here is an example](http://jsbin.com/oyohal/2/edit).

EDIT: Below is how I'm implementing the tooltip now using OnaBai's method. It's still is not working correctly though. The if condition should should run the first block is there is no characters with in the p tag.

```
 tooltip: {
    visible: true,
    border: {
        width: 1
    },
    font: "10px MS Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif",
    template: function (a) {
        if (!$(".tooltip-alert p").text().trim().length) {
            return mTypeName + "&nbsp;" + a.value + unitName + " <br/>" +
                   a.dataItem.measurementtime + " " + a.dataItem.measurementdate + "<br/>" +
                   "<div class='tooltip-alert'>" +
                   "<p></p>" +
                   "</div>";
        } else {
            return mTypeName + "&nbsp;" + a.value + unitName + " <br/>" +
                   a.dataItem.measurementtime + " " + a.dataItem.measurementdate + "<br/>" +
                "<div class='tooltip-alert'>" +
                    "<div class='statType-icon alertIcon-" + a.dataItem.alertid + "'></div>" +
                    "<p>" + a.dataItem.alertname + "</p>" +
                "</div>";
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: The problem is that `seriesHover` is triggered before the template being displayed so you are actually doing nothing trying to hide it. Try doing the `$(".statType-icon").hide();` without condition and you should see that never get hidden (no matter of empty / no empty `p`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to hide it, define the `tooltip` as a function that applies the logic. Example:

```
tooltip: {
    visible: true,
    font: "10px MS Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif",
    template: function(a) {
        if (!a.dataItem.alertname) {
            return "Unit name &nbsp; " + a.value + " some variable<br/>" +
                    a.dataItem.measurementtime + " " + a.dataItem.measurementdate + "<br/>" +
                    "<div class='tooltip-alert'>" +
                    "</div>";
        } else {
            return "Unit name &nbsp; " + a.value + " some variable<br/>" +
                    a.dataItem.measurementtime + " " + a.dataItem.measurementdate + "<br/>" +
                    "<div class='tooltip-alert'>" +
                    "<div class='statType-icon alertIcon-" + a.dataItem.alertid +"'>BG img</div>" +
                    "<p>" + a.dataItem.alertname + "</p>" +
                    "</div>";
        }
    }
},
```

Use as logic condition what is going to be the content of the HTML `p`.

Comment: Thanks! Going to try this out real quick and see how it works.

Comment: Added an edit to the original post show you how I'm implementing it now. Using your method It is still not working properly I imagine it has something to do with my if conditions logic.

Comment: According with the recently edited information, the content of `p` element is `a.dataItem.alertname`. So this should be the condition, you cannot ask for the content of `p`  if you still did not generate it. See my answer with the condition as I understand it.